# Why is my app failing in a conditional operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, caching

my code is

```
export default function useFetch(fetchFunction, param) {
  const cache = useContext(cacheContext);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(fetchReducer, initialValue);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (cache.page[param]) {
      dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.success, payload: cache.page[param] });
      console.log("cache");
      return;
    }
                  // other code below
)
```

But my app is failing in the conditional operator. Im expecting that if cache.page[param] is empty, keep executing the code below. For example, if i got the param `"0"` i get the error `"TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null"` and my app crashes

Comment: does it work for non zero param value?

Comment: Well as the error says, `cache.page` is undefined, so trying to access its properties will cause an error. Are you loading `cache.page` asynchronously?

Comment: @Vaibhav no, I can't even access the list of pages in my app because it crashes (this function is executed when the homePage component loads). But isn't it supposed that if cache.page [param] is null, the app should ignore that and keep executing the rest of the code?

Comment: @Jayce444 no, cache.page is just localStorage data

Comment: Try: `if(!cache || !cache.page) return;` as first line of useEffect()

Comment: As @Jayce444 pointed out `cache.page` is _`null`_, so you should first verify that it's not `null`. You can do that easily with the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator like so: `cache.page?.[param]`.

Comment: Ok but you ignored the first part of my comment. If `cache.page` is undefined, then `cache.page[param]` will throw an error, as the error message indicates - you can't access properties of something that's undefined. So check that it's defined before trying to access it's param property, e.g. `if (cache.page && cache.page[param])`, or use the optional chaining operator

Comment: Ok I got it, I get it. Thank you so much guys! 

edit: i added "(cache.page && cache.page[param])"  and  now is working fine :)